# Kerberos authentication using Java is failing

Tags: java, kerberos

My client has run in to some trouble with their java application (I have not played in Java land in a long time).  The application uses Kerberos for authentication and works great up to Java 1.6.30.  But as soon as they upgrade to Java 1.7.11 they begin getting the following error:

```
javax.secrutiy.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain the Principal Name for authentication.
```

The JVM is running on Windows 7 in a windows domains so we are authenticating against AD.
Was there a breaking change made between releases?  Is there a code change they need to do to get this fixed?  Or did somebody on the Java team goof up?
TIA

Comment: You'll need to get some debug information to go on.

Comment: Considering how many potential unknown variables are involved, this is very much a "too localized" question. If there was a breaking change between releases of whatever, downgrade said whatever to see if it fixed things. Is there a code change someone needs to do? Maybe, maybe not, we don't know what the problem is so we can't tell. Did someone goof up? There's just no way for us to know that at all.

Comment: It's unlikely the upgrade broke anything. It sounds to me that your client might have done a little more than upgrade the JRE. I just wrote a small app today that is being used on both Java 6 and 7, and it seems to work a charm when authenticating against our AD. Do you perhaps have the code used for the authentication handy; if so, post it up! Something else to consider is authenticating through LDAP. Although this is a perfectly sound way to authenticate, I would recommend trying to get Kerberos working since its sole purpose is used for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could be running into this potential problem.

http://www.javaactivedirectory.com/?page_id=93

Java 6 doesn't respect the registry value while java 7 does.